# 5k player 4k movie H264 codec isn't using hardware acceleration on GTX970 GPU

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-geforce, codec, h.264, 4k-resolution

The machine I am using: OS Windows 10, 6Gb Ram, NVidia 970GTX and AMD FX6300 CPU, the media player is the latest `5k player` display is 4k TV and I am trying out 4k movies, but they lag really badly.

I am enabling `Hardware acceleration` on 5k player for h264 both encode and decode, but in task manager when I run the movie CPU goes to 95% while GPU is at 15% at most, so I am guessing that GPU acceleration isn't being enabled.

**Why would 5k player wouldn't be using GTX 970? How do I debug this further?**

Comment: According to their website it uses Nvidia Cuda which, I believe, is only available with the full drivers package. Try installing/updating the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia first thing I did, also tried vlc and Splayer, and restarting PC, none helped one bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player that worked for me was `Cyberlink PowerDVD 18 Ultra` (not affiliated).

Cpu still stayed at 90%+ however GPU went up to ~40% and lagging disappeared.

I have also had installed GeForce Experience and updated drivers, although that didn't do it for other players, still getting like 2fps.